# Disable / configure "play" link on facebook shared publication from a facebook game

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-share, facebook-tabs

I have a facebook app which can only display content inside of a page tab app because it needs to know the page id to know which content to display. 
My app needs to have the "invite friends" functionality and was created on the 2.4 API version, so I had to define my app as a game.

The problem is :
when I share something from a facebook page tab app, there's a "play" link on my publication and that link redirects to the app, not the page tab app.
I couldn't find any information to know where to redirect the user.

Can I disable this link? 
Or configure it to redirect the user to the page tab app? 
Or can I have the "invite friends" functionality in any other category than game in  the 2.4 API?

I use the facebook JS SDK to share :

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'share',
        href: $(this).attr('href'),
    },
    function(response){});
```

Thanks for your answers and advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from a facebook comunity group :

" Your app needs to be a game and have a canvas implementation, if you want to use invitable_friends. It needs to be playable on canvas, without redirecting anywhere else first. If that is not the case, or your app is not really a game – then you can not use it.

Possible alternatives are listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite "